# Sending email, via javamail smtp, results in messagePartiallyDelivered on a completely successful send

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

Sending email, via javamail smtp, with 2 addresses listed in MIME headers but only 1 address used in send function seems to result in a messagePartiallyDelivered, regardless of the fact that the 'one' address provided to the send function successfully received the message.

Is this the expected behaviour ?

The javadocs for javamail are not very well filled out, so it is hard to tell if this is the behaviour I can expect with any implementation of javamail (be it sun/oracle, or gnu).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mail.smtp.reportsuccess set?  If so, that's the expected behavior.

Otherwise, it would be helpful to see the [protocol trace and debugging out](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: I forgot to mention that this 'messagePartiallyDelivered' is seen from the listener. I do have at the moment (in my testing) reportsuccess set, but I would not have expected it affects also the event!

Comment: Right now the exception throwing and event sending are coordinated so that you'll get consistent results.  If you think that coordination should be broken in this case, please file a bug with the [JavaMail open source project](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail).